# Detached entity passed to persist error with h2 database

Tags: jpa, h2

I'm trying to use JPA with a h2 database to built an application for management.

Right now i'm trying to save a Contact in the database but i always get this error when trying to merge a new contact.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ccc.foo.Conact
```

Here is what i have right now:

Class Contact

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table
public class Contact implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email

    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String email{
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailAddress = email
    }

    //gets and sets and to string
```

Class that initiates the Database and fill with some contacts (hard-coded by now):

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class InitiateContacts{

private static final String[] contactsFirstNameData = new String[] { "Foo", "Foo2" };
private final String[] contactsLastNameData = new String[] { "FooLastName",  "Foo2LastName" };
private final String[] contactsEmailData = new String[] { "aa@bb.com", "bb@aa.com" };

private EntityManagerFactory emfactory = null;
private EntityManager entitymanager = null;

public InitiateContacts() {
    this.emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DATABASE_NAME");
    this.entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager();
    initPersistentContacts();
}

private void initPersistentContacts() {
    Query query = entitymanager.createQuery("Select COUNT(c) from Contact c");
    Long result = (Long) query.getSingleResult();

    if (result == 0) {
        this.entitymanager.getTransaction().begin();

        for (int i = 0; i < contactsFirstNameData.length && i < contactsLastNameData.length
                && i < contactsEmailData.length; ++i) {
            Contact contact = new Contact(contactsFirstNameData[i], contactsLastNameData[i], contactsEmailData[i]);
            this.entitymanager.merge(contact);   //ERROR HERE!
        }
        this.entitymanager.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

As i said before i get the error in the line :this.entitymanager.merge(contact). In debug mode i saw that the exception is only raised in the second loop (and i saw the params and everything was fine). I thought the problem could be the id but i changed it to be auto generated and problem continues.

I saw other post and here is some solutions provided by another users that doesn't work for me:

- CascadeType.MERGE - I dont need this because i'm not using a multiple relation with another class (OneToMany, ManyToMany,etc)
- Use merge instead persist make no difference
- Use a auto generated ID

By now i have no more ideas

Thins that maybe usefull

Persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="DATABASE_NAME" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <!--  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>-->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>


        <class>foo.Contact</class>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:h2:C:/path/to/folder" />


            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="qwerty" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="create" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
```

ps: I can provide something else if it's relevant

Comment: I believe you need `EntityManager.persist()` instead of `merge()`. I can only guess how is this connected to the error, however for new entities `persist()` is the appropriate method.

Comment: Even with this.entitymanager.persist(contact); .. i get the same error

Comment: First I have to try to understand what you want to achieve. Do you have some rows in the `contact` table that you want to update with first and last name and email?